# From string line to string array

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I need to get  string array from string line. It is possible ?

```
main(){
 string x = "This is string";

 //do something, function or... i don't know...
 //result

 cout << string[0] << string[1] << string[2] << endl;

 //cout << "This" << "is" << "string" << endl;
}
```

How to do this array ??! Ty ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c

Comment: What do you expect `string[0]`, `string[1]`, etc. to be????

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string-in-c

Answer (score 1):

You can tokenize a string into a container of strings like this:

```
string data = "quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
stringstream input(data);
vector<string> res;
copy(
    istream_iterator<string>(input)
,   istream_iterator<string>()
,   back_inserter(res));
```

[demo.](http://ideone.com/NvhikN)

Answer (score 0):

For this use std:string:substr like this

```
string = "This is string";
string2 = string.substr(8,6) //string2 now equals "string"
```

the 8 refers to the position of the first character

the 6 refers to number of characters from that point

ensure you have `#include <string>` in your declerations

more info on std:string:substr [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/)